# nested compiler directive -HOW TO DO

Tags: delphi, nested

How to make the one, two and three compiler directives be active if DEBUG is defines?

```
   $DEFINE DEBUG
   $IFDEF DEBUG
   $DEFINE ONE
   $DEFINE TWO
   $DEFINE THREE
   $ENDIF
```

Comment: This is not valid code at all. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue you're having, and include the **complete, exact** error messages you're getting. Delphi allows any number of compiler directives, so any problem you're having is the result of something you're doing wrong, and without the **exact** code you're using, it's impossible to tell what it is you've done and tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Like you've already surmised:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG }
  {$DEFINE ONE }
  {$DEFINE TWO }
  {$DEFINE THREE }
{$ENDIF }
```

In Delphi, a compiler directive is a special form of a `{}` comment (or `(* *)` comment for that matter), starting with the `$` sign followed by a keyword and then any parameters needed.

Comment: its conditional directive, so I want if debug is defined, then ONE,TWO AND THREE should be defined

Comment: @maths That is exactly what this code does. Simply remove `$DEFINE DEBUG` and let the compiler define it for you

Comment: @Remy  Where is debug then defined.. Dont need to define  elsewhere?

Comment: @maths by default, `DEBUG` is defined in the project options `Conditional Defines` field in debug build configurations. This is even shown in the 1st screenshot in the documentation: [Project > Options > Building > Delphi Compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler)

Comment: Is it related to  options delphi compiler conditional defines and  then "value from  Debug configurations.

Comment: I can only add one define in program code, a second define line is not accepted,  but if I add  to Din gui  options ...Delphi Compiler... value from debug configuations the second define is accepted 

---------------
 {$Define GX_DEBUGLOG}    // accepted
 {$Define Use_Code_Site} //not accepted , so have to add in Options GUI

Comment: @maths You can add defines wherever you want. You can have multiple values defined in the Project Options. You can have multiple `{$DEFINE}` statements in your code. It is really confusing to understand what you are actually having a problem with. "*a second define line is not accepted*" - why? What exactly is stopping you? Please edit your question to add more details. Right now, you risk having this question closed for lack of detail/clarity.

Comment: thanks .. its clear now that the Define Condition can be set from the compiler directive GUI (Project options>compiler directives)  and also in the IDE code editor. The latest is the one that is guilty. I was confused about how to set  related to configuration alternative.